# Convert string to CLLocationCoordinate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Is it possible to convert a string to a longitude/latitude value? I managed to convert the coordinate to a string, but I cannot find a way to revert the process

Comment: `CLLocationCoordinate` has `init!(latitude latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude longitude: CLLocationDegrees)` and `CLLocationDegrees` is a `double` (`typealias`). Now if you issue is about parsing the `NSString` that's another thing. What does it look like? What have you tried?

Comment: This question is not very clear. Give an example of the lat/lng string you are talking about. Is it a pure float, does it contain North/South, East/West indicator characters etc. It is impossible to answer the question as currently formulated.

Comment: So far, i tried this :

var lat_str: String = "45.5436754765"
            var lati = Double((lat_str as NSString).doubleValue)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My bad, it was a simple type. If anyone ever struggle on how to convert a string to coordinates, here's the correct syntax :

```
let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(([longitudeString] as NSString).doubleValue), longitude: Double(([LatitudeString] as NSString).doubleValue))
```

Answer (score 9):

Another way to convert:

```
let latitude = (latitudeString as NSString).doubleValue
let longitude = (longitudeString as NSString).doubleValue
```

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3

```
let lat = Double(String1)
let lon = Double(String2)

 let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:lat!
                        , longitude:lon!)
```

`CLLocationCoordinate2D` is a double value it can convert string into double See in above example

Answer (score 1):

```
var currentLocationLatitude = "45.5626" // your string latitude
var currentLocationLongitude = "45.5626" // your string longitude

var currentLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D! //location object

currentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:currentLocationLatitude.toDouble() ?? 0.0, longitude: currentLocationLongitude.toDouble() ?? 0.0) 



extension String
{
    /// EZSE: Converts String to Double
    public func toDouble() -> Double?
    {
       if let num = NumberFormatter().number(from: self) {
                return num.doubleValue
            } else {
                return nil
            }
     }
}
```

You can take string latitude and longitude from you API response and in CLLocationCoordinate2D variable, pass with converting to Double value.
I have also added extension for converting string to double.

Answer (score 1):

might help

```
let Latitude = ("41" as NSString).doubleValue
let Longitude = ("29" as NSString).doubleValue
```